# Unable to grab data from MongoDB to use on Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently trying to grab data from MongoDB via Mongoose, and show it with Express. However, this is the following error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: /home/node/CSci-Project/views/account.ejs:31
    29|                     <% if (req.user.twitter.token) { %>
    30|                     <p>
 >> 31|                         <strong>id</strong>: <%= user.twitter.id %><br>
    32|                         <strong>token</strong>: <%= user.twitter.token %><br>
    33|                         <strong>display name</strong>: <%= profile.twitter.displayName %><br>
    34|                         <strong>username</strong>: <%= profile.twitter.username %><br>

Cannot read property 'twitter' of undefined
    at eval (/home/node/CSci-Project/views/account.ejs:13:31)
    at account (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:691:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at /home/node/CSci-Project/app/routes.js:67:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at isLoggedIn (/home/node/CSci-Project/app/routes.js:105:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/node/CSci-Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

I thought I had passed it through with callback and with findOne being asynchronous, so I'm not sure where to go from here. Here are the relevant files:

- [views/account.ejs](https://gist.github.com/Permanently/243920255f001e8bcd4899baa0a3d65b) (the page I'm trying to view)
- [app/routes.js](https://gist.github.com/Permanently/582a92ff92ec04d7e7ca40693fbc0f55)
- [app/models/user.js](https://gist.github.com/Permanently/29c020f42d36b7cd5a77ed3aec86a67d)
- [app/models/profile.js](https://gist.github.com/Permanently/464a2bab7bf2232c75ce18f95aaa1b03)

Sorry if I've made any simple mistakes in here - I'm new to Node and I've come over from C#, so I'm still in the process of learning the differences. Also worth noting that data is definitely on MongoDB and it all exists.

Comment: You are testing on in the `if` on `req.user.twitter.token` but are trying to write information on `user.twitter.token` ... said in another way, are you using the right properties? I'm looking at the `Cannot read property 'twitter' of undefined`

Comment: @Syska On config/routes.js, req is passed through as req to Express, and userInfo is passed through as user. Can also confirm that the data is written to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to figure it out, after countless attempts. My mistake was that I thought by putting `var userInfo = UserModel.findOne` it would just simply print itself out as userInfo.id, userInfo.token, etc, but no. I actually meant to use the output that's inside of `UserModel.findOne`.

**app/routes.js**

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) {
    app.get('/account', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        var UserModel = require('./models/user.js');
        var ProfileModel = require('./models/profile.js');

        UserModel.findOne({
            'twitter.id': req.user.twitter.id
        }, function (err, userInfo) {
            if (err) {
                return res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                ProfileModel.findOne({
                    'twitter.id': req.user.twitter.id
                }, function (err, profileInfo) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.redirect('/');
                    } else {
                        res.render('account.ejs', {
                            req: req,
                            user: userInfo,
                            profile: profileInfo
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
};
```